# Jquery Accordion Error:: Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-accordion

**Included Scripts**

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Accordion Script**

`

```
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
        $("#tabs").tabs();


</script>`
```

**Html**

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
<div>First content</div>
<h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
<div>Second content</div>
```

Why i am getting this error???Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion

**Updated**

One thing i would like to mention is : my script is working fine with tabs

Comment: Have you included the jquery base file? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: debug your script using Fire Bug or press ctrl + shift + k in firefox and check why it is occured. May be your script confilcted. this occured when you use another ajax tools (which use older jquery version) and jquery simultaneously.

Comment: you have not put your scripts under $(document).ready(function({
}); blcok please sorround your jquery in it to ensure scripts are not executed before they are loaded and available to your browser

Comment: I am having the same issue on MVC + Jquery + partial views, apparently has to do with some script .js files being included in file twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try previous version of jquery

`jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js`

`jquery-1.3.2.min.js`

For Accordion it works for me.
and if you also want to include tabs in your view then use latest release of jquery(you are using as of now)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar errors in error reporting that we use on our website. These errors are really very infrequent. That is, the vast majority of pages displays execute fine without generating an error. But then some browser comes along, has no trouble with most of the javascript or jquery, then throws some random error. This has puzzled me a while and I was about to open a similar question.

My theory, based on much observation, but not "fact" is that somethings happens in the browser which throws the error in a non-repeatable way. That is, it is not a problem in your code, but rather a problem in the browser.

I would hope for a more authoritative answer than this one, or some proof that what I am suggesting "cannot happen".